# C# Pass Json to HTTP Post Request

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to pass in a Json String as a parameter for a HttpWebRequest along with a URL. The request will hit the methods fine, but every time the parameters are null. I've tried to follow many examples like this one, but with no success: [How to send json data in POST request using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676611/how-to-send-json-data-in-post-request-using-c-sharp)

Here is the sample object that will be serialized and passed

```
Amount amount = new Amount
{
    currencyCode = "EUR",
    amount = 1234
}
string JsonParameters = amount.ToJson();
var result = Methods.ExecuteHttpPostRequestWithJson("http://localhost:51581/Home/Test", JsonParameters);
```

Json Parameters serializes correctly into

```
{"currencyCode":"EUR","amount":1234}
```

Here is the method I'm try to create. I've tried multiple ways but they end up being null each time.

Here is the method that will be called

```
public static string ExecuteHttpPostRequestWithJson(string URL, string Json)
    {
        string result = "";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {;
            streamWriter.Write(Json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the method that gets correctly hit, but with null parameters for both currencyCode and amount.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string currencyCode, string amount)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        Test = "It worked"
    });
}
```

Comment: you are creating an object in javascript. try creating a class in c# with currencyCode and amount and use the object of that class as parameter in your function

Comment: I've tried I get currencyCode = null and amount = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what was suggested in the comment by [Nouman Bhatti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430556/nouman-bhatti) -- defining the amount class in your service as well as updating your service's POST method signature to expect that object -- also use the `[FromBody]` attribute

class

```
new Amount
{
    currencyCode = "EUR",
    amount = 1234
}
```

New POST method signature

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test([FromBody]Amount amount)
```

Comment: That was the solution! I've tried changing it to Amount before, but never did the [FromBody]. Thanks!